# Inserting element into DOM at a specific place is not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, insertadjacenthtml

I would like to insert an `input type=text` field between `p` and `input type=submit` using `insertAdjacentHTML`, but it’s not working. A string `[object HTMLInputElement]` gets inserted instead of an `input` element.

What am I missing? Please share if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Here is my code:

```js
const form = document.forms[0]
const submitButton = form.querySelector("[type='submit']")

const foobar = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {
  type: "text",
  name: "Foobar",
  readOnly: "true"
})
  
submitButton.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", foobar)
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    …
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <input type=submit value=Submit>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`insertAdjacentHtml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is used for inserting HTML text, a string. To insert DOM nodes, use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

```
submitButton.parentNode.insertBefore(foobar, submitButton)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) does just what it sounds like - it inserts *HTML*, like the string `'<input value="foo">'`. It doesn't insert elements.

If you want to insert an adjacent element, use [`insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement):

```js
const form = document.forms[0]
const submitButton = form.querySelector("[type='submit']")

const foobar = Object.assign(document.createElement("input"), {
  type: "text",
  name: "Foobar",
  readOnly: "true"
})
  
submitButton.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", foobar)
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    …
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <input type=submit value=Submit>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```